# MS Access IN operator not returning rows

Tags: ms-access, in-clause

Using an MS Access database (I know), the query below

```
SELECT * FROM PageImage WHERE (PageImage.Rooms) In ('1');
```

only returns rows when the 'PageImage.Rooms' column has a single value like 1

The actual data stored in the 'PageImage.Rooms' column is a comma separated list like 1,2,3 stored as a string, but no data is returned when this is the case.

From the above query & referring to the image below, only row 342 is returned, when I expect 341,342,343 to be returned

[image]

Comment: Your expectation is incorrect.  The `IN` operator doesn't work that way.

Comment: Do you know what would return my expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to scrap the multi-value string field & go down the correct route of creating a mappings table

Answer (score 2):

Given that PageImage.Rooms stores a genuine comma-delimited list as you specified in a comment (i.e. it is not an Access 2007+ multi-value field), you really have created a bit of a mess.  A table containing such a column is for that reason completely un-normalized (not even in first normal form).  Query and data consistency issues are to be expected.

The usual way to model a many-to-many relationship such as you have would be with a separate table.  In this case, however, since the PageImage entity seems to have no data other than its Id, you could do it in the same table.  Either way, whichever table models the relationship should have a separate row for each (PageImage.Id, Room) pair, and those pairs should be a composite key for the table.

With the structure you have now, the query you seem to want could be implemented like this:

```
SELECT * FROM PageImage
WHERE
  PageImage.Rooms = '1'
  OR PageImage.Rooms LIKE '*,1'
  OR PageImage.Rooms LIKE '1,*'
  OR PageImage.Rooms LIKE '*,1,*'
;
```

As Gord Thompson observed, that could be expressed more compactly, and perhaps more efficiently, as

```
SELECT * FROM PageImage
WHERE (',' & PageImage.Rooms & ',') LIKE '*,1,*'
;
```

As you can tell, it gets worse if you want to compare against multiple room numbers in the same query.

Bottom line: strings containing comma-delimited lists are just strings as far as the database is concerned.

Comment: If this query is run from within Access itself then the `*` wildcard may be applicable for the [LIKE](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-ca/article/Like-Operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931?CorrelationId=ef274ded-dde9-413f-92e5-f15f7e5cad83&ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA) operator. Also since such a query will require a table scan anyway, perhaps `WHERE (',' & Rooms & ',') LIKE '*,1,*'` would be more compact.

Comment: Thanks, @GordThompson.  Fixed the wildcards to Access's deviant convention, and added your more compact expression.

Comment: When and where is that deviant convention held?  :-)

Comment: Seattle, Washington, USA, @HansUp.  Every day of the year. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your input John, I didn't create this mess, I inherited it, I was looking for a way to work with the database in its current form, before thinking about re-writing the schema

Answer (score 0):

The IN operation is the same action as performing an expanded `OR` statement where 
`SELECT * FROM PageImage WHERE (PageImage.Rooms) In ('1','2');`

is the same as

`SELECT * FROM PageImage WHERE PageImage.Rooms = '1' OR PageIMage.Rooms = '2';`

Dealing with a partial match requires the `LIKE` keyword so `SELECT * FROM PageImage WHERE PageImage.Rooms LIKE '*1*';` will return any field that has a one in any position within the field.